# What changed my WordPress .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, wordpress

My WordPress site went down with an error 500. After looking around, I restored the .htaccess and that fixed it. My question is what in WordPress could have changed the .htaccess by itself? Do plugins sometimes do this? What about adding sub-domains within CPanel? Any way to prevent this?

The .htaccess was originally this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

It keeps getting changed to this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether anybody will be able to offer more than speculation - we'll see. Anyway, if it happens again, remember to make a copy of the faulty file.

Comment: Wordpress changed my .htaccess when I changed my permalinks, so I guess it's possible for wordpress, maybe even for plugins - can't say anything to that though.

Comment: You don't mention what was changed within the `.htaccess` file.  I know that when you change the permalink settings in the Dashboard, Wordpress writes to the `.htaccess` file.  So yes, technically Wordpress _can_ write to it.  I have no idea how it could have just done it spontaneously?

Comment: Thanks, I added the before and after of the .htaccess. What was it trying to do or any clue what keeps causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permalinks as well as any Cache plugins can do that.  However, you should have saved the "messed-up" .htaccess so that we could see the contents of that, vs. what it was originally...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the messed up one

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-fRewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Here is the good one

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

My .htaccess file kept getting reset like that because my site was hacked. Here's a potential solution: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/191570/20963